# Entity framework core and ChangeTracker memory consumption

Tags: entity-framework

**Using entity framework core 6:**

In my aspnet core project, my controllers get a DB context through dependency injection with service setup like the following:

```
...

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString));

...
```

The controllers in the application do several database operations that are not inter-related. Means:

**Step 1:**

Query Table A, get a large result, then do CUD on it

`_dbContect.SaveChanges();`

**Step 2:**

Query Table B, get a large result, then do CUD on it

`_dbContect.SaveChanges();`

**Step 3:**

Query Table C, get a large result, then do CUD on it

`_dbContect.SaveChanges();`

**Question:**

1- Should I call `_dbContect.ChangeTracker.Clear();` after each `SaveChanges();` to save memory?

2- Is there a better way of handling _dbContect excess change tracking memory consumption?

3- Should I even be worry about  change tracking memory consumption?